# Problema Con Mostrar Fotos en tablas mediante php usando ruta de imagen

Tags: php

```
<?php
while ($registropoductos=$resproducto->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
     
  echo '<tr class="ta">
  <td>'.$registropoductos['cod_inf'].'</td>
  'echo '<img src="'.$registropoductos["img_inf"].'" width="50px" heigth="50px"><br>';'
  <td>'.$registropoductos['img_inf'].'</td>
  <td>'.$registropoductos['pla_inf'].'</td>
  <td>'.$registropoductos['mot_inf'].'</td>
  <td>'.$registropoductos['est_inf'].'</td>
  <td> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1" onclick="editar('.$registropoductos['ced_per'].')">Editar /</a>&nbsp;<a href="eliminar.php?id='.$registropoductos['ced_per'].'&accion=pago">Eliminar</a></td>
  </tr>';
}
?>
```

Ese es mi ciclo el fallo es, en el segundo echo  la pagina me dice esto "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in ..."
he intentado diversas formas para tratarlo pero en todas me ha dado error, porfavor agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: el error dice esperando un , o ; te falta terminar la línea con un ; antes del siguiente echo

Comment: si, existe un echo anterior, que es el que le da la forma a  tabla

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a un problema con la formación de la cadena, se te fue una comilla.

Intenta esto:

```js
while ($registropoductos = $resproducto->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

    $string =
        '<tr class="ta"> 
            <td>' . $registropoductos['cod_inf'] . '</td>' .
        '<img src="' . $registropoductos["img_inf"] . '" width="50px" heigth="50px"><br>' .
        '<td>' . $registropoductos['img_inf'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $registropoductos['pla_inf'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $registropoductos['mot_inf'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $registropoductos['est_inf'] . '</td>' .
        '<td> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1" onclick="editar(' . $registropoductos['ced_per'] . ')">Editar /</a>&nbsp;<a href="eliminar.php?id=' . $registropoductos['ced_per'] . '&accion=pago">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>';

    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya aparecen las imagenes pero ahora se salen de la tabla pero ya se soluciono el problema general

Comment: acabo de notar que deje un linea de codigo extra que era con la que estaba confirmando que si era la imagen correcta, pero aun asi  me resulta fallido hacerlo ya que el img src va dentro del td

Comment: es decir
'<img src="' . $registropoductos["img_inf"] . '" width="50px" heigth="50px"><br>' .
ese img src va donde esta el  $registropoductos['img_inf'], perdon el abuso es la primera vez que uso imagenes 
        '<td>' . $registropoductos['img_inf'] . '</td>' .